# I want to convert my json object to my java onject using fromJson() of GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json object as like this:

```
[
    {
        "created_at": "2014-07-01 5:01:10",
        "status": "in progress",
        "device_id": "1234",
        "order_details": [
            {
                "item_id": 1,
                "quantity": 2
            },
            {
                "item_id": 2,
                "quantity": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And in java I have two classes order and order details as like this:

1) Order.java

```
package dto;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Order 
{
int order_id;

String created_at;
String status;
String device_id;
ArrayList<Order_details> orderList= new ArrayList<Order_details>();

 public int getOrder_id() {
    return order_id;
}
public void setOrder_id(int order_id) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
}

 public String getCreated_at() {
    return created_at;
}
 public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
    this.created_at = created_at;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getDevice_id() {
    return device_id;
}

public void setDevice_id(String device_id) {
    this.device_id = device_id;
}

public ArrayList<Order_details> getOrderList() {
    return orderList;
}

public void setOrderList(ArrayList<Order_details> orderList) {
    this.orderList = orderList;
}

 public void attachOrderDetails(ArrayList<Order_details> member) { 
        this.orderList = member; 

}
}
```

2) Order_details.java

```
  package dto;
  public class Order_details 
  {
   int item_id;
   int quantity;
   String item_name;
   double price;

    public int getItem_id() 
    {
 return item_id;
    }
    public void setItem_id(int item_id) 
    {
this.item_id = item_id;
    }
    public int getQuantity() 
    {
 return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) 
    {
this.quantity = quantity;
    }
   public String getItem_name() 
   {
return item_name;
    }
    public void setItem_name(String item_name) 
    {
this.item_name = item_name;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
return price;
   }
   public void setPrice(double price) {
this.price = price;
    }

   }
```

now i want to convert above json object to the object of order class
To achieve this i have tried it:

```
Order order= new Order();
order= gs.fromJson(json,Order.class);
System.out.println("order"+order);
```

but it throws exception as follows:

```
   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected           BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
at       com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapte   rFactory.java:176)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:791)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:757)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:706)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:678)
```

Please, help me out to convert my json to my java object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `[` in your json says its holding an array or Order objects. So you need to make a list of orders rather than a single order class.

```
List<Order> order = new ArrayList<Order>();
order = gs.fromJson(json, order.getClass());
System.out.println("order" + order);
```

Or using type token as

```
List<Order> order = new ArrayList<Order>();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Order>>() {}.getType();
order = gs.fromJson(json, listType);
System.out.println("order" + order);
```

Alternatively to work with your code directly you need to modify your json to

```
{
  "created_at": "2014-07-01 5:01:10",
  "status": "in progress",
  "device_id": "1234",
  "order_details": [
    {
      "item_id": 1,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "item_id": 2,
      "quantity": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That helped me out.. i just removed square brackets around json object.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using GSON,then you should be more aware of case sensitive w.r.t key name and variable name.

```
either change variable name to 
ArrayList<Order_details> order_details= new ArrayList<Order_details>(); instead of 
ArrayList<Order_details> orderList= new ArrayList<Order_details>();

or 

change json key name to orderList instead of order_details
```

Comment: I got that inner arraylist order_details and its underlying object by just renaming orderList to order_details.you have solved my another issue. Thank you

Comment: I would like to mark as correct to this answer but At a time i can select only one. and the exception com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 was resolved by Syam S's suggestion which actually i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string can not cast directly to your class because your json contain array of the parameters of class `Order` and to convert it into class object you need list of `Order` class so that this array can be converted to list of `Order`.
For that you need to take `List<Order>` of Order class as shown below :

```
List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Order>>(){}.getType();
orderList = json.fromJson(jsonStr, listType);
```

May this will help you.